# powershell desc analogy - list output columns and their types

Tags: powershell, reflection

If there anything like SQL's `describe` so I don't have to look through a "blanket" of `| select *` output before actually selecting the few columns that I need?

E.g. `Get-Process`'s possible output columns include `Id`, `Name`,`VirtualMemorySize` as well as about three dozen others. I want to get that list of column names, preferrably with their types.

Comment: `desc` specifies sort order, not a column or set of columns.

Comment: @alroc: (facepalm) I mean the `desc` that's the abbreviation of `describe`, a stanalone command.

Comment: FYI `desc` and `describe` are proprietary to Oracle (they're not standard SQL), so only people familiar with Oracle will understand what you're talking about with that command.

Comment: I learned it in MySQL but fair enough. Made it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this for human viewable output then use `Format-Table` e.g.

```
Get-Process | Format-Table Name,Id,PM -Auto
```

Note: if you have *lots* of output do not use the `-AutoSize` parameter as that buffers up all its input to determine the optimal size of each column.  If you don't specify that parameter, PowerShell will split up the screen space evenly based on number of properties selected but it will display each object as soon as it is received.

For the "column" names, that is bit trickier.  You can easily get the list of "ALL" the property names e.g.:

```
Get-Process | Get-Member -MemberType Properties
```

If you want just the properties that would normally be display by Format-Table then you need to inspect the View Definition for the System.Diagnostics.Process type in `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\DotNetTypes.format.ps1xml`.

Comment: Nope, I'm interested in listing all column names of the output rather than the output.

Comment: Sweet! Just the thing. The added bonus is it lists all 4 types of properties!